# SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() Not working with BIGINT on MySQL 5.6.11 When Using a Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, last-insert-id

I'm posting a new question following my previous post "[SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() Not working with BIGINT on MySQL 5.6.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491849/select-last-insert-id-not-working-with-bigint-on-mysql-5-6-11)"

In any case, after further investigation I found that the LAST_INSERT_ID() was not working because I had a trigger BeforeInsert on the table that I had a problem with.

So basically my problem is when calling LAST_INSERT_ID() after the INSERT statement it returns 0, because I have a BeforeInsert as a Trigger on this table.  If I comment out this Trigger, it works fine and the LAST_INSERT_ID() gives me the correct number.

Any ideas how to over come this problem ?  Below is the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `mydb`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`%`
TRIGGER `mydb`.`Booking_BINS`
BEFORE INSERT ON `mydb`.`Booking`
FOR EACH ROW
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one

BEGIN

DECLARE iNextBookingId INT;
SET iNextBookingId = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE     TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='Booking');
SET NEW.BookingId = iNextBookingId; 

INSERT INTO AuditTrail  (AuditTrailId,UserId,ActionType,TableName,RowKey,FieldName,OldValue,NewValue,LoggedOn) VALUES
(UUID(),NEW.LastChangedBy,'INSERT','Booking',NEW.BookingId,'HotelId',NULL,NEW.HotelId,NOW()),
(UUID(),NEW.LastChangedBy,'INSERT','Booking',NEW.BookingId,'AgentId',NULL,NEW.AgentId,NOW()),
(UUID(),NEW.LastChangedBy,'INSERT','Booking',NEW.BookingId,'SupplierId',NULL,NEW.SupplierId,NOW());


 END$$
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of your trigger?

Comment: Updated my question with the Trigger

Comment: Heavens, why are you doing this?!?  Why not allow MySQL to set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field value for you, and then perform the FK insertions (using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` or similar via API) subsequently, within the same transaction if so desired?

Comment: Or maybe I could just move the Trigger to the After Insert event ?

Comment: @eggyal Also, I am allowing MySQL to set the AUTO_INCREMENT value in my normal INSERT statement.  The above Trigger is Auditing anything added to the table

Comment: `SET NEW.BookingId = iNextBookingId;` is the bit with which I take issue.  I'd get rid of all that and simply put the `INSERT ...` statement directly into an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, if indeed this design is necessary at all.

Comment: OK, I agree I can move it to the AfterInsert trigger.  I assume this is what is causing the problem I posed in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a race condition by assuming `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.AUTO_INCREMENT` can be used as `NEW.BookingId`.  As soon as you have more than one session firing this trigger concurrently, you'll run into trouble because both sessions will try to assign the same value to BookingId.

Also, auditing inserts in a BEFORE trigger is risky because the insert could fail for a variety of reasons, and then you might get phantom audit data.

You should move your auditing into an AFTER trigger.  That way you know that the INSERT succeeded, and the auto-incremented BookingId will have been generated in the conventional way.